# Angular 16 Lazy Loading and Nested Child Routes Issue

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm trying to set up angular routing in lazyloading but the problem is that as soon as I have nested child routes, my routing system no longer works.

**app-routing-module.ts :**

```html
export const rootRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    data: {
      title: "Dashboard"
    },
    loadChildren: () => import("./modules/dashboard/dashboard.module").then(m => m.DashboardModule)
  },
  {
    path: "user",
    data: {
      title: "Utilisateur",
    },
    loadChildren: () => import("./modules/user/user.module").then(m => m.UserModule)
  },
  {
    path: "groupUser",
    data: {
      title: "Groupe d'utilisateur"
    },
    loadChildren: () => import("./modules/group-user/group-user.module").then(m => m.GroupUserModule)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(rootRoutes, { enableTracing: true })
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**dashboard-routing-module.ts (routing for module Dashboard):**

```html
export const dashboardRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    title: "Dashboard",
    data: {
      title: "",
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: '/dashboard'
      },
      {
        path: "dashboard",
        title: "Dashboard",
        component: HomeComponent,
        data: {
          title: "Home"
        },
        children: [
          {
            path: "group_host/:group_host_id",
            title: "Groupe Host",
            component: GroupHostDetailComponent,
            data: {
              title: "Groupe Host"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(dashboardRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

Link stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-tznewx?file=package.json

I'm trying to access the GroupHostDetailComponent via the following url: dashboard/group_host/1. But every time I call this url, it calls me the HomeComponent view

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: could you provide a stackblitz to reproduce the issue also have you added `router-outlet` tag to the parent?

Comment: @JSmith here I am providing you with a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-tznewx?file=package.json

and yes I did provide the <router-outlet></router-outlet>

Comment: I'm unable to preview your project on stackblitz could you correct it please?

Comment: @JSmith it's corrected

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @JSmith yes, that fixed my bug. i was a bit stupid not to have noticed ^^'. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside the parent component here it's `home.component.html`

[working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cjueke?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodules%2Fdashboard%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmodules%2Fdashboard%2Fdashboard-routing.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmodules%2Fdashboard%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmodules%2Fdashboard%2Fdashboard.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts)